# Como fazer um git push para o bitbucket programaticamente usando BASH em Ubuntu16.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, bitbucket

Tenho um script bash rodando em ubuntu 16.04 cujo objetivo é criar um projeto (folder) laravel e em seguida criar esse mesmo repositório no bitbucket e depois fazer o push do conteúdo para o repositório que acabou de ser criado no bitbucket.

A única parte que está faltando é o push para o bitbucket.
Aqui está o código:

```
//Criar o repositório no bitbucket  
curl --user $USR_BITBUCKET:$PSSWRD_BITBUCKET https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/ --data name=$NEW_REPO_BITBUCKET

//Vá para o diretório de Laravel que foi criado programaticamente
cd cd $HOME_PATH/vhosts/$VHOST
//Inicialize como git
git init
//Mudar os privilegios do folder do projeto
sudo chown -R $UBT_USER:www-data $HOME_PATH/vhosts/$VHOST/
//Config inicial do git    
git config --global user.email "${GIT_EMAIL}"
git config --global user.name "${USR_BITBUCKET}"
//Add and commit
git add .
git commit -m "First commit - bash"
git status    

// ----   Ate este ponto esta tudo certo

//Fazer o push para o bitbucket - Aqui é a duvida
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que seja mais ou menos assim.

```
https://$USR_BITBUCKET:$PSSWRD_BITBUCKET@bitbucket.org/$USR_BITBUCKET/$VHOST.git 
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: exatamente...  só falta uma pequena alteração no se codigo. muda la a sua resposta `git remote add origin https://$USR_BITBUCKET:$PSSWRD_BITBUCKET@bitbucket.org/$USR_BITBUCKET/$VHOST.git` aqui o $VHOST=repo